# How to do (m)Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization with integers ? (real life problem) ("mathematicalized reformulation")

Tags: matrices, linear-algebra, na.numerical-analysis

New edition of the question, "mathematicalized" (thanks to Gerhard).

Consider and integer valued n*n matrix M, with integers elements in the range -N < m < N.
I want to find integer-valued approximate orthogonalization of this matrix X. 
Means that values of X are integers in the same range and matrix is "close" to the honest Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization of initial matrix X_honest.

Is there some bound norm ( X- X_honest) > f( condition(M) ) ?
E.g. it is difficult to solve the problem if original matrix is ill-conditioned.

Is there way to find such matrix in reasonable complexity O(n^3) ?
(and not using sophistaced arithmetical representation of numbers e.g. 
emulation of floating point or rational or Chinese remainder theorem is not allowed).

===========
Try to do orthogonalization of these column vectors.
Problem is that the 3-th and 4-th are almost the same.
Is there some nice solution ?
Or some no-go result can be proved that with integers I cannot do this ?
Or I can do it but not within reasonable complexity O(n^3) ?

[ 32768.000000 , 0.000000 , -1424.000000 , -1422.000000 ; ...

24219.000000 , 10476.000000 , 3107.000000 , 3109.000000 ; ...

-18861.000000 , -22098.000000 , 32768.000000 , 32768.000000 ; ...

-20462.000000 , 32768.000000 , 3939.000000 , 3940.000000 ];

More details.
The processing units used in fast or low-energy computing devices like mobile phones, GPS, signal processors do not support floating point arithmetics.
I.e. they can work we integers e.g. -2^15 <= m <2^15-1
And when you do multiplication of such two must truncate result back to this region
before you can do any other operation.

The task is do [Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt)
of a matrix on such device.
When I do it I see that resulting vectors are far from orthogonal
Matrix of normalized scalar products is the following:

```
1.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.1764

0.0000    1.0000    0.0000    0.5667

0.0000    0.0000    1.0000    0.4438

0.1764    0.5667    0.4438    1.0000
```

Is there some nice way to cure the problem or no ?
I would prefer that complexity (i.e. number of operations) is not much bigger that in standard algorithm. i.e. O(n^3).

Comment: You can represent rationals in the algorithm exactly as fractions (pairs of integers). Making it fit in two-byte integers may be a bigger problem, especially since your input numbers do not seem to fit there in the first place (32768).

Comment: Rational number arithmetics is impracticle. It will increase much number of cycles.

I am testing in MatLab so for the moment do not care much about small overflows like you mention.

Comment: Vague comment: would it help to use modular arithmetic for various moduli and use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to patch things back together?

Comment: There are different approaches to take depending on what the problem really is.  Suppose your first column has exactly two nonzero components, and they are both 1.  What are you supposed to return as an answer?  If we knew what was to be done with the result, we might find something that would serve the application better.  Right now, the chances for bad or inaccurate output are high.  Is that acceptable?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman,  2011.10.27

Comment: In what world do mobile phones not support floating point? ARM architecture very much does (even vectorized). @Matt: it would help, until the last step, where you would overflow.

Comment: @Alexander: what are you testing in matlab?

Comment: I am voting to close, since this seems to have very little to do with research arithmetic (and having once implemented a version of Mathematica graphics on the Mac+ in fixed point arithmetic, I know whereof I speak).

Comment: Do as you feel best, Igor.  I have a feeling there are some meaty numerical analysis issues, perhaps a result that says there is a condition number above which a nice answer is guaranteed, and that the condition number may be computed quickly.  I hope others take more time in casting closing votes.  Also, if the user is dealing only with 4x4 integer arrays, there may be a nifty answer. Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.10.27

Comment: @Gerhard: the point is, there is a huge literature on fixed point algorithms which surely address these points, and are probably implemented in FORTRAN '77, just look at the back issues of TOMS. But this is no longer of practical interest, and while it is of some mathematical interest for reasons you say, standard texts on matrix computation (Golub-van Loan, e.g.) will tell you all about the general mathematical wisdom on the subject. Using the wisdom for 16 bit fixed point numbers is no longer mathematics, but engineering.

Comment: I confess I hope to see an engineering solution to this problem, with enough mathematics that I would learn something from it.  If I possessed your viewpoint, I too would encourage closing, except with more of a pointer to the right area for the poster.  I still hold out hope that the poster will provide enough additional information that a nice mathematically appealing piece of engineering will result.  For example, a lookup table of precomputed orthogonal matrices is what I had in mind, with some rotational 
tweaking.  Gerhard "Some Engineering Is Also Mathematics" Paseman, 2011.10.27

Comment: How are you computing the orthogonal vectors? Pure Gram-Schmidt is the obvious incorrect choice; have you tried using Householder reflections? Those are going to be stabler for a given precision than standard Gram-Schmidt when columns are near-orthogonal. Trefethen and Bau's book would be a good place to look, and Demmel's book would have a comprehensive collection of algorithms for specific situations.

Comment: @Igor ARM processor are not used for PHY level algorithms (where all mathematics lives i.e. decoding, channel estimation etc.), ARM - just application level cores, hard calculations are done by ASICs and FPGAs as far as I understand. Although I more familiar with operator's equipment. Here for sure, there is no ARM for heavy calculations.

Comment: @Nilima I am using modified GS. 

Comment: I am glad I helped inspire the new formulation.  I am not competent in numerical analysis to tell you when to expect a good solution.  Also, it may be NP hard to arrange the columns in a way so that you will get a good answer.  If you can cheaply compute the dot products so that you can see where the problem columns might be, you may be able to do a quick partial G-S.  Perhaps Nilima can tell us what to do from there.
Gerhard "Likes To Help Other Mathematicians" Paseman, 2011.10.28

Comment: @Gerhard thanks for Yours inspiration. I am not sure this formulation is correct. Probably corrected formulation is - 1) if do GS orthogonalization in fix point how far will we get from true orthogonalize basis... 2) How can we correct naive fix-point GS to get better result  ? 
 But probably to find correct formulation is by itself not bad question. There is some phenomena for sure - that it is difficult to orthogonalize ill-conditioned matrix in fix-point, finding the correct formalization I think a natural part of the mathematical work, I surprised that colleagues feel negative about it.

Comment: The negativity is not about the correct formulation or even finding it.  Igor's objection (as I understand it and I agree with it) is that the initial version of the question seemed more like an embedded systems problem than a mathematical problem.  Cool problem, wrong forum (if indeed an embedded systems solution is required).  The current formulation is more suitable for MathOverflow.  Gerhard "In My (Not) Humble Opinion" Paseman, 2011.10.28

Comment: The matrix appears nearly rank deficient, so I'd suggest using methods for rank-deficient QR decompositions with column pivoting. The key would be  Householder/Givens rotations rather than projections. As Igor suggests, Golub and van Loan's book has lots on the numerical analysis of this. Demmel's book will point you to algorithms for your particular situation.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if your microprocessors can handle fixed point arithmetic then here is a matlab commercial that should do it: http://www.mathworks.com/products/fixed/demos.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/fixedpoint/cordicqr_demo.html

Gram-Schmidt is not numerically stable even when you can use floating point so my guess is that you will have many problems if you stay that course.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. But let me remark that small modification called "modified-GR" (see Wiki) as far as I understand is numerically stable in float. I am using it.

Comment: Yes modified-GR (ie do GR twice) is stable. Are you able to use fixed precision on your device?